# The sum of the coefficients in the expansion of $(2+3x^2-x^5)^n\cdot(2-3x^2-x^5)^{2n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Show that the sum of the coefficients in the expansion of $$Q(x)=(2+3x^2-x^5)^n\cdot(2-3x^2-x^5)^{2n}$$ is a positive number.

I know that we are supposed to substitute with $x=1$ as I have seen this method in sample problems. This way we'll get the desired sum. I don't understand why it works, though. If we look at e.g. the polynomial $P(x)=5x^3+4x-7, P(1)=5+4-7=2$ which is really the sum of the coefficients. But the polynomial $5x^3+4x-7$ is in its standard form. Why doesn't it matter if it is, or is not? Anyways,
$$Q(1)=(2+3-1)^n\cdot(2-3-1)^{2n}=4^n\cdot(-2)^{2n}$$ Can we simplify further?

Comment: "Sum of coefficients" means the sum of all coefficients that appears when you expand the whole thing out.  So it doesn't matter if I give it as, for example, $(x-1)^2$ or $x^2-2x+1$ or $x(x-2)+1$ or whatever equivalent forms.

Comment: Here $Q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{15n} A_k x^k \implies \sum_{k=0}^{15n} A_k=Q(1)$$

Comment: @ZAhmed, I don't understand this notation, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A coefficient of $10$, for example, would mean $10$ occurrences of the term. To know the number of occurrences of a term like $10x^5$, you should simply put $x=1$.

In a more general (or abstract) sense, it could be generalized to even any real coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

It works because once you expand the expression and single out every term, you are interested in the coefficients, and you want to ignore the variables. A simple and nice working way to do that is by replacing every occurrence of the variable by its coefficient and that is done by substituting $1$ for every variable.

Take an exanmple, $$(x+y)^3=1x^3+3x^2+3x+1$$

Sum of the coefficients is $1+3+3+1=8$, which is both the sum of the coeffcients of all the terms and the value of the polynomial for $x=1$.

Comment: thanks! .........